# What does it mean when the MSI log file says "Note: 1: 2729"?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I ran an install like this:

```
  msiexec /i   Module.msi  /l*v msilog.log
```

And in the resulting logfile, I got a bunch of message like:
`Note: 1: 2729` .  What does it mean?

Is there a rosetta-stone for understanding what all those messages mean in an msi log file?

**EDIT**:
here's an example snip of the msi log file:

```
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:332]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:332]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:332]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:332]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:332]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:332]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:332]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 1
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (D4:8C) [12:16:44:348]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
```

Comment: Can you post a logfile or a snippet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout:

[How to Interpret Windows Installer Logs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx)

[Windows Installer Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Q107675: ERRDOC: Windows Installer Error 2729](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q107675)

Code 2729 is "Install engine not initialized."

There's very little out on this but my best read of this error code is that the msiexec client side is trying to spin up the msiexec server side ( windows service ) and it's going through a loop logging that it isn't up and running yet.   After a few iterations it's up and the install continues.   Take a look at the following log snippet and tell me if this is pretty much what your log looks like.

```
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:406]: Package name extracted from package path: 'msse.msi'
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:406]: Package to be registered: 'msse.msi'
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:406]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:437]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:437]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:437]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2729 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (A4:DC) [22:12:14:453]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
```

PS- The (c) after MSI means the log entry originated from client side.  Also you might find this utility helpful:

[Wilogutl.exe (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372811(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: yes, that's what my log looks like, too.  Let me check out those links.